# ngOnchange doesn't detect dynamic changes

Tags: angular, e-commerce, ngonchanges

I'm using angular for developing eCommerce app. I'm Using OnChange lifecycle hook to detect changes in the cart component and calculate total price. However, changes are not being detected.

Typescript Code:

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Device } from '../../shared/Device.model';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-cart-calculator',
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
      templateUrl: './cart-calculator.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./cart-calculator.component.scss']
    })
    export class CartCalculatorComponent implements OnChanges {
    
      @Input() cartProducts: Device[];
      @Input() quantities: number[];
    
      constructor() { }
    
      totalPrice: number = 0;
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
      ngOnChanges() {
    
        this.totalPrice = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.cartProducts.length; i++) {
          this.totalPrice += this.cartProducts[i].devicePrice * this.quantities[i];
          console.log(this.quantities);
        }
      }
    }
```

Template part:

```
<app-cart-calculator [quantities]="quantities" [cartProducts]="cartDevices"></app-cart-calculator>
```

Comment: What's the html?

Answer (score 3):

Array is an object in javascript so you have to pass new array every time you want it to be detected by ngOnChanges(). So for eg:- you pushed a new value to array like :-

```
       arr.push(4);
```

after that you need to give it a new reference :-

```
 arr = [...arr];
```

Comment: I solved it by detecting the change in the array length.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `SimpleChanges` parameter to your implementation (`ngOnChanges`) of `OnChanges`.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {      
  this.totalPrice = 0;
  const products = changes['cartProducts'] && changes['cartProducts'].currentValue;
  this.totalPrice = products.reduce((totalPrice, product) => totalPrice + (product.quantity * product.devicePrice), 0);
}
```

You also have reference problem, you are mutating your property `cartDevices` in your *parent* component instead of re-assigning its value.

Answer (score 0):

**`ngOnChange` - A lifecycle hook that is called when any data-bound property of a directive changes.**

Here you are binding an array,and that is being treated as object.That means `ngOnChange` will be fire when you will send new Object,in our case case a new Array(means new reference id).

Angular uses the equality check operator === to detect when an input(s) to directives changes.
The === operator checks for reference changes in the objects it's checking.

And here you are changing content of Object,Not Object reference.

`ngOnChange` will be triggered,in case of any kind of Object,when there will be a reference change means new Object.

**So 1st solution is**

```
this.cartDevices.push(device);
this.cartDevices = [...this.cartDevices];
```

Or form an array and assign that,by doing this it will change reference of `this.cartDevices`

```
this.cartDevices = devices
```

**2nd Solution**
By binding a custom object with angular `trackBy`. angular will comapare that Object's equality by `trackBy` index rather object reference and this will improve performance also.

```
<app-cart-calculator [quantities]="quantities" [cartProducts]="{trackBy:cartDevices.length,data:cartDevices}"></app-cart-calculator>
```

```
  ngOnChanges() {
    this.totalPrice = 0;
    this.cartProducts = this.cartProducts.data;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.cartProducts.length; i++) {
      this.totalPrice += this.cartProducts[i].devicePrice * this.quantities[i];
      console.log(this.quantities);
    }
  }
```